# how to scroll to exact item after scrolling stop in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I make a simple demo of `carousel`. I am showing three cards at one time (two full cards and one small portion). When I click `next` and `previous` button it behave the same always by showing three cards except when user react to end there I am showing only `two cards`. This functionality is working fine, but  I am facing one issue.

The issue is when I scroll I want `snipped` my item.
I have items like `blue`,`red`,`green`,`yellow`,`blue`.

Issue.when I scroll `5px` or `10px` it will snipped in other words if we scroll `blue` after stop scrolling scroll it should be show `red`,`green`,`yellow`.

Input If I scroll this part .

[image]

**Expected output** it should scroll to next slide

[image]

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-greider-3k0md?file=/src/App.js

```
const onscroll = (e) => {
    const ratio = Math.round(
      parent.current.scrollLeft / slide.current.offsetWidth
    );
    console.log(ratio, "ratio");

    const newIndex = ratio >= 1 ? ratio : 0;
    setxx(newIndex);
    setIndex(newIndex - 1);
  };
```

any update .?